# Rspec Test Failure due to missing link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Failures:

1) AuthenticationPages signin with invalid information followed by signout 
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no link with title, id or text 'Sign out' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:28:in`block (5 levels) in '

This is a failure from my rspec test although I kind of know what is wrong but I dont know why its wrong.

My Rspec test:

```
describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with valid information" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
        fill_in "Email", with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

    describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end

end
```

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

Sessions Helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def signed_in?
   !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

end

_header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <%= link_to "TechnoEdge", root_path, id: "logo" %>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
                    <% if signed_in? %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
                        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Account <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Settings",'#' %></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    <% else %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Based on the embedded ruby code, the header should show sign in when there is no session created. However, I cant seem to be able to get it to work and I suspect that the problem lies within the sessions helper but I cant figure out what is wrong though.

Thanks in advance!

git source: https://github.com/tgxworld/sample_app

Comment: Seems like you haven't actually signed in, so why would you expect there to be a sign-out link?  E.g. you're not filling in the username/password in your form + clicking "login".

Comment: Hmm while running on local, I sign in but the link remains unchanged at 'Sign in'.

Based on my rspec test, theres the before (visit signin_path) and before (click 'Sign in;) am i right to say that would have logged in as a user?

Thanks!

Comment: My expectation would be that it would not actually sign you in.  You'd need to fill in the email + password somewhere and then submit that form.  Then I'd expect you to be signed in.

Comment: O sorry! I noticed my mistake. I placed the test under the wrong rspec condition. The test has passed but I still cant get Sign out to appear after I sign in as a user.